# Linking Images to Websites in Delphi using TMS Web Core

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, tms, tms-web-core

I am trying to link an image to a website using the `TWebImageControl` and the `TWebLinkLabel` components, I am aware that I should use an `onClick` event however how would the code be written in order for the link to work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to link to websites or open URLs. One is using `window.open` and the other one is using `Application.Navigate`.

## Application.Navigate

The `Application.Navigate` function takes two parameters. The first parameter is the URL and the second is the `TNavigationTarget`.

Navigate to a URL in a new tab:

```
Application.Navigate('https://www.bing.com', TNavigationTarget.ntBlank);
```

Navigate to a URL in the same tab:

```
Application.Navigate('https://www.bing.com', TNavigationTarget.ntPage);
```

## window.open

Here's a little function that I wrote to work with `window.open`:

```
procedure OpenURL(URL: String; NewTab: Boolean = True);
begin
  if NewTab then
    window.open(URL, '_blank')
  else
    window.open(URL, '_self');
end;
```

The `NewTab` parameter is to specify whether you want to open the link in a new browser tab or in the same tab as your website.

So if you want to navigate to let's say "https://www.bing.com/", then you can write the following code in your `onClick` event to call the function:

```
OpenURL('https://www.bing.com', False);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [TWebLinkLabel](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/tweblinklabel/) you only need to specify valid URL link as part of its caption and it automatically changes into hyperlink at runtime.

As for [TWebImageControl](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebimagecontrol/) you can specify the URL from which the image is loaded. But of you would like to open a different image when clicking on `TImageControl` then you would need to use OnClick event and provide a custom URL as it was shown in **Shaun Roselt's** answer